# Is further education and training only my responsibility?

Tags: software-industry, education, training

Some time ago I read an article like "Your career is your responsibility and yours alone" and I wonder if this is true.

I work as software developer but the company I work for never spend any time and money on training and education of their employees.

So I decided to take matters in my own hands. I pay for my courses myself and attend them in my holidays. For me that is not a big problem. I like to learn new things and to hang out with developers from all over the world is fun.

But it's like I am paying and the company gets the benefit from it. And somehow I feel like I am the only one bringing new technologies to the company.

Is further education and training only my responsibility or should my company take its part?

Comment: if this leads to real improvement of your skills, this should mean that you get more appealing at job market, and in order to keep you there, company will sooner or later have to pay you more - to stop you from leaving for a better position. Training and education, if done right, **enhances your employment options**. So, eventually, company will pay anyway - either that, or you will [leave them for better job](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/10088/168 "as discussed eg here")

Comment: I would say its not *only* yours but it **is** *mainly* yours

Comment: What is different from [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/how-can-i-approach-career-development-with-a-boss-who-doesnt-seem-to-support-th)? Most of those answers on that question answer your question.

Comment: At least you've learned something to negotiate for on your next job.

Answer (score 3):

It's not very beneficial to talk about what the company "should" do, unless you are asking how to convince the company to do something that they aren't doing.

In *your* company at *this* time, the company you work for "never spends any time and money on training and education of their employees". So you are doing what you must do - decide what you personally need to further your career and make it happen. Your career is *your* responsibility - not someone else's.

Many companies have programs to invest in training and education of their employees. The idea is that this is a benefit to the employees (and thus part of a competitive benefit package which makes their company more appealing to potential employees). And it's also viewed as a benefit to the company - they can retain employees longer and they can have more educated, better-trained employees. It's unfortunate for you that your company chooses not to do this, but the "should" part is a company decision.

Now if you want to try and get your company to start funding your education/training expenses, you might sit down with your manager and/or HR rep, point out what you have been doing, and emphasize the advantages to the company that you see. But, to be honest, I suspect you won't be telling them anything they don't already know, but have chosen not to implement.

Obviously, the company is not getting *all* the benefit here. If you weren't getting at least *some* of the benefit, you probably wouldn't be doing this. Clearly you enjoy it. And while it may not be immediately apparent, you are building a foundation for future career growth - either with your current company, or with a different employer. Focus on that aspect, and don't worry so much about what your employer should or shouldn't be doing - you'll be happier.