# How do I try out new job roles?

Tags: position

I have a technical job presently but I would like to experiment with other roles-  how can I do this? When there are distinct 'roles' in companies you might be in one that isn't causing you to make progress so how do you find out how to make progress - you have to experiment. How does one find the space and time and connections to do this?

Comment: Hi Andrew and welcome to [workplace.se]. Your question is very brief and without further narrowing down the issue, will generate a whole host of answers, unlikely to be very helpful. Would you mind [edit]ing in some more info in, to help us help you and other better? Take a look at the [help], too.

Comment: Well what you're saying in your comment is pretty far from what's in your question already. What's pretty obvious in your mind, might not be to other readers who would like to help.

Comment: [Relevant related question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11197/2322)

Answer (score 2):

Most employers in my experience don't want to try people in roles where this no evidence that you'll be ale to do the role.

The trick is to add skills and experience to you current job by doing more than is asked and helping others who are doing the things you want to try. This will give you at least business knowledge of those other roles that you can try an leverage when asking for new assignments/tasks and jobs.

Comment: Is this dependent on the company culture? How fluid are roles to let people do more than asked? Surely in a technical job - the requirements are well defined and then delivered. Doing more than be a diversion of focus or it takes me further into the technical role.