# Ignoring my management and previous companies experience skills

Tags: management, career-development

I am an experienced Director of Database Applications who previously has successfully supervised a team of DBAs and has made a few successful database conversions to/from: MySQl, PostgreSQL, MS SQL. Despite my formal job title "Manager of Database Applications", my current company is using only 25% -30% of my capacity of managing just a single database platform. None of my other experience (especially management and other DB platforms) is used or planned to be used. All Database related questions are solved without my input, I am not asked to contribute or/and capitalize on my previous database management experience across other platforms. Essentially, as a dog I a given a bone  - "chew this thing - you are doing a good job with MS SQL 2005 - keep it at, and do not ask questions"

How can I step up to the broader responsibilities if my manager is actively ignoring any input from me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I approach career development with a boss who doesn't seem to support this?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/how-can-i-approach-career-development-with-a-boss-who-doesnt-seem-to-support-th)

Comment: Who's saying "and do not ask questions"? Are you senior enough you can set your own direction - can you use your 'spare' time to find other useful projects to do for the company (practical, knowledge-sharing, analytical, etc.) and take the results to your bosses? i.e. is there any scope for carving our your own role?

Comment: This question should be referenced for everyone who asks why "overqualified" candidates are turned down.  This is a thoroughbred being forced to be a carnival pony, and he's miserable.

Comment: How long have you been there? This is often normal the first 6 months to a year.

Comment: Is it possible that your current boss sees you as a threat?

Comment: Can you clarify if your current organisation actually needs your broader database experience? What if they don't use those other platforms?

Comment: i checked out your profile, because your issue looked familiar. And indeed you've had several questions in the last few weeks with similar content, plus on-boarding to a new job and working for a single manager. Is it about your new job? This may change the way people look at the problem and you may have different answers.

Answer (score 17):

Polish up your CV and start finding a new job. If your manager is actively ignoring you, it's time to move on.

Comment: I ordinarily would downvote an answer telling someone to leave, rather than deal with the problem at hand, but I honestly don't see any other viable course of action.  +1, reluctantly.

Answer (score 10):

If you are as experienced as you say, why did you take this postion knowing they were not a cross-platform company and using a ten-year old version of a database? This is so clearly a company that doesn't want you to change what they are doing - they even view upgrading the SQL server to be too risky.

It is not an ordinary thing to migrate databases to other databases. Those a are one-time, special projects that typically are very risky and time-consuming and so not taken up lightly. In all my years of database work, I have never had an employer ask for this except to upgrade within the same stack. If your database is working, why would you want to change to a  new one and take all the risks of the data conversion?

So I am at a loss as to how any of this was a suprise to you.  Did you enter this postion thinking you would change them? That is like entering a maariage thinking you are going to "fix" your partner.  Exactly what did you expect from this postion? What do you expect from a new postion if you change jobs? You need to think about the implications of what they do and look for a job that suits your desires mnot think you will change them to be the way you want them to be.

Perhaps consulting is a better environment for you.

Comment: While I broadly agree with the thrust of your answer, I would note where you say *"Did you enter this position thinking you would change them?"* - sometimes that can be the exact remit for a new hire. And it's possible that others not with the program can attempt to thwart that. Yes it's silly and childish but it happens.

Comment: Being hired to change things is very dangerous. You are likely to encounter resistance that you do not have the political pull to overcome when you are new. If no one from within the organization wants to step up and drive this change, it is very, very unlikley that you will be successful as a new person. I have seen many people run into this through the years. Those who succeeded worked within the system at first until they made the connections and people started to rely on their expertise, then they started proposing new things. This can take a couple of years though.

Comment: yes precisely. I think understanding whether or not that is the case here is important. There's a big difference between "trying to redefine my role to develop my career" and "caught in a power struggle between two people senior to me who see things differently"

Comment: Yes the solution woudl be different.