# Manager is blocking advancement within company

Tags: job-change

My wife works for a company that employs people in every state and country.  She has been working really hard to get all the certifications and badges to move into a corporate position.

After applying and being denied for several corporate positions, even those she is way over qualified for, she finally called the hiring offices.  They told her that her current district manager does not want her to leave, thus ruining her chances for advancement.

Is there anything she can do to get a good reference and a chance to move up?

Comment: The district manager needs to be hauled up in front of HR for unethical and amoral behaviour that affect a person's normal chance for career advancement.  Can she report it to HR?

Comment: Seems difficult to believe the HR dept would even know information like that. The current district manager is not likely to announce his intention to prevent her advancement.  Did the HR dept know this by reviewing a file while your wife was on the phone, or did this take a few days/weeks of research?  More details please...

Comment: If a manager says "this person is essential for my department," that may be enough for HR to not put her name forward for a possible transfer. Or if she's been paid to acquire certification/badges/etc. the manager might be saying that she still owes time to the department.

Comment: Sounds like your wife needs to chat with the manager. If HR said it's because he doesn't want her to leave the first step is to find out why.

Comment: Very related question - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11197/2322

Comment: It may be time to go over the district manager's head and arrange for a private conversation with the division chief or someone of that sort. The difficulty of changing jobs is often proportional to how many levels of management up you have to go to find someone whose tree includes both jobs...

Answer (score 5):

Your wife is going to have to make a decision.  There are three ways this can go. 1) She sits it out and waits for her manager to either change his mind or leave the company 2) She goes to HR and says "am I valuable enough to the company that you would rather have me working here in another capacity than working for another firm?" or 3) she just starts looking for another job.

It may very well be that her manager does have enough pull that he can get away with this, or it may be that the stated reason is not the real reason she is not advancing.  If they decided she's just not advancing, saying "you're too essential to let go" might be a not particularly subtle appeal to her vanity.

Since it is unlikely that she'll ever know the "real" answer (if the stated one is not truthful) she's going to need to decide how important it is to her to "move up".  And if it is important, how important is it to move up in *this* company?  Important enough to risk what might happen if she calls their bluff?

Personally, I wouldn't risk it.  It's better to just leave the situation behind.  Look at it from her manager's point of view.  If she isn't willing to just put his "needs" before her career plans, what would he have to lose in torpedoing her out of spite?  He might not be skanky enough to do that but he's already showed himself to be willing to engage in unethical behavior, even if he doesn't think of it that way.

And if she is inclined to just leave things as they are and see what happens, that may be a mistake.  In every case that I have personally been aware of, once a person decides they want to leave a position, the relationship they have with coworkers and supervisor/employer changes.  Even if they are essential to a position (and nobody is *really* essential, not even if they *invented* the product the company is selling) they have suddenly put themselves outside the "trust" barrier.  Everyone is aware that they were thinking of leaving and even if they are no longer trying to leave, there's no way to prove that.